# How to stick two unrelated elements together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I'm working on an interface and I require something that would stick two unrelated elements together. Well, the most important element will be the "boss" and the other element called "employee" will follow the "boss" around and will change it's position accordingly.

This is the markup:

```
<div class="boss"></div>
<div class="employee"></div>
<div class="boss"></div>
<div class="employee"></div>
<div class="boss"></div>
<div class="employee"></div>
<div class="boss"></div>
<div class="employee"></div>
```

This is the jQuery I wrote:

```
$('.boss').each(function( i, obj ){

        var Pos = $(this).position();
        var ModuleWidth = $(this).outerWidth();

        $(this).next('.employee').position({
                my: 'right top',
                at: 'right top',
                of: $(this)
        });

});
```

So I'm iterating through all the .boss classes and aligning all .employees to the right top of boss. They are supposed to always stick. But if I edit the html from the boss within chrome Developer Tools the .boss element will become smaller and larger **and the .employee will not re-position** its self accordingly. I would like to make .employee always reposition its self.

Later Update:

This http://screencast.com/t/F0RO7ODF is the kind of behavior i'm looking for. The gray box is the BOSS and the orange box is the EMPLOYEE. These 2 element's have a wrapper and i'm actually moving the wrapper. But i'd like a solution without a wrapper. Note: The organge box's position is irelevant.

Comment: UM, why don't you wrap them? And of course they will not move since the position is not based on the element position, but the document. You would need to call the code to recalculate the position.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying. But i wouldn't like to add another element to wrap them, since that would highly pollute the HTML. I need a full jQuery solution to this.

Comment: Post your css - even better - a fiddle, so we're able to understand what you're achieving with the layout.

Comment: What's the real issue here? Editing in dev tool which created the problem which is not a real issue unless you expect your users to do the same thing.

Comment: Adding another element will pollute the HTML? Really? How does adding markup to define structure polluting it?

Comment: Think i'm misunderstood. I'm trying to create an interface layer over a live preview section of random elements. These elements will be live edited. Thus i need that .employee element to always stick to the .boss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this has been answered already, but here is an alternative which does not use any hierarchy between the two elements (even though that might not be the best practice):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="boss"></div>
<div class="employee"></div>

<div class="boss"></div>
<div class="employee"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$.fn.invisible = function() {
    return this.css("visibility", "hidden");
};
$.fn.visible = function() {
    return this.css("visibility", "visible");
};

$(".boss").draggable({
    stop:function(e) {
        var employee_horizontal_position= $(this).offset().left+$(this).width();
        var employee_vertical_position= $(this).offset().top-$(this).height();   

        $(this).next().visible();
        $(this).next().offset({top: employee_vertical_position, left: employee_horizontal_position});
    }
});

$(".boss").on("drag", function(e){
    $(this).next().invisible();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.boss{
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: grey;
    float:left;
    margin-top:100px;
}

.boss:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.employee{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    float:left;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/ktxo4f6s/2/

I tried to make the employee hidden while the boss is being dragged as shown in your screencast.

Comment: Good exmample but breaks with multiple boss/employee elements.

Comment: if i had the rating i'd probably +100 your answer thanks man, thanks a lot, life saver right here. ill try to evolve your solution to work for multiple bosses :) thanks.

Comment: Awesome, glad to be of help. Updated the answer to work with multiple elements by using the next() function, but I don't know if that's the best way. It would break if your employee would not be always the next element after the boss on the DOM.

Comment: @carlosHT the `next()` will not work if a boss has more than one employee since it only grabs the immediate single element after and no others. Suggest also using `.css('visibility', 'hidden')` instead of `hide();` to prevent the bouncing. To resolve the multiple employees use `nextAll('.employee')` but will need to recalculate position and css to account for the left float. That's where the hierarchical approach makes it easier to develop.

Comment: The .employee can be an ul with multiple lis for example so that's not a problem

Comment: @regis that's how I meant by the hierarchical approach, by adding a wrapper to employee to group them together.

Comment: Updated the javascript and the fiddle with the visibility solution.

Answer (score 3):

n general when wanting elements to be in relation with each other they should be grouped together within an element.
To represent hierarchies it is best to also develop your html to honor the hierarchy you wish to represent.
This will force the behavior as you displayed in the video when moving the boss element.

For this particular example it may also be expanded upon with departments or roles.
See JSFiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/9dw5dvqw/

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/en85bm9h/

***HTML***

```
<ul class="bosses">
    <li class="boss">
        <span class="boss-name"></span>
        <ul class="employees">
           <li class="employee">
               <span class="employee-name"></span>
           </li>
           <li class="employee">
               <span class="employee-name"></span>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="boss">
        <span class="boss-name"></span>
        <ul class="employees">
           <li class="employee">
               <span class="employee-name"></span>
           </li>
           <li class="employee">
               <span class="employee-name"></span>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

***CSS***

```
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body,
html{ height: 100%; }
ul{ list-style: none; overflow: hidden; float: left; }
li{ overflow: hidden; }

.bosses{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.boss{ margin: 20px 5px 20px 0; float: left; }
.boss-name{ display: block; background-color: #eee; float: left; width: 120px; height: 80px; cursor: move; }
.employees{ float: left; width: 50px; height: 120px; background-color: red; }
```

Comment: I guess i'll use the hierarchy approach. Tho a friend of mine just showed me some apps that do stuff like i need them to do without hierarchy :) check out https://moqups.com/ to see what i mean. An element from the work area has no hierarchy between it and it's control panel.

Comment: While it is possible it is not best practice. Which is why I used the term generally. Why make it more difficult to read and develop than it has to be (KISS)? Unless you need functionality that would break the hierarchy I suggest this approach. Let me know and I can provide you with different approaches. Or see the answer by @carlosHT